# Apply animate to new elements that have been added dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The code i current have is this.

```
function update (){
    latest_id = $('#image:first').data('position'); /* == 12 */
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../web/update/" + latest_id + "",
        success: function(data) {
            $('#my_like').after(data);
            $('.newly-added').animate({"margin-left": "+=66px"}, "fast");
        },
        error: function(response) {
            alert("failed");
        },
    });
}

setInterval(function() {
  update();
}, 4000);
```

But because the element has been newly added it doesn't receive the new animate part. I done some research and found .live but that needs something to start it, e.g a click.

Comment: Could you provide a little more context? What is `.newly-added`? Is that part of the AJAX return `data`? If so I do not see why your current code would not work, as long as you call `animate` after the element you are animating is added to the DOM.

Comment: Sorry, the data that is returned is a image with the class newly-added :)

Comment: If there's any way you can put together a JsFiddle (maybe not with ajax, but faking a response or something) or show us a live example of the page it'd be helpful. Also try calling `console.log($('.newly-added'))` right before your `.animate()` to make sure it really is in the DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed, there was a issue with jquery I was including.